# How can I display a link and not a button to submit my ASP.NET MVC2 Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm just starting out in ASP.NET MVC (and web applications in general, as I've only really worked on console apps before), and was wondering how to display a link instead of a button for submitting a form?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">Please don't right-click, shift-click, ctrl-click or middle-click this link, or do anything else that seems like an obvious thing to do with links beyond just clicking it, as it's a dummy link pretending to be a submit button</a>`

Given the issues of people treating links like links (crazy of them, I know) it may be better to do `<span onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">Submit!</span>` and then use CSS to give it a pointer cursor.

Comment: A slightly more general solution w/ JQuery is `$(this).nearest('form').submit()`. There may be more than one form per document.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking to post the form via a hyperlink. You're not going to find any helpers built into the framework which support this action because it isn't a recommended practice for security reasons. That said, here's an approach with is quite safe and should work for you. [jQuery Delete Link With Downlevel Support](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/30/delete-link-with-downlevel-support.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [onclick JavaScript event to your hyperlink](http://programmingbulls.com/how-submit-form-using-javascript) that submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using CSS to hide the submit button's border and background color (and otherwise style it so it has the appearance of a link) instead, so that your form is still be accessible if JavaScript is disabled.